# How do I count specific rows in GROUP BY SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that joins two similar queries into a single temporary table.   I then build a result set from that single temporary table.

Part of the final result set should include count of which rows are "Equities" and "Options". To solve this I added hard coded columns.

A rough/simplified ERD looks like this:
[image]

Equities have a hard coded 1 in EquityType column and Options have a hard coded 1 in the OptionType column.   By the way, the TH.Type column also contains unique values to distinguish a row from Equity or Option (values will be either 'Equity' or 'Option').

I feel my solution is, at best, a hack; and there has to be better alternative.

My sql is for MySql, but I do not believe the answer is database specific.  Here's the sql:

```
-- step 1 get equities
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PositionDetails AS
    (
    SELECT TH.Id,
        TH.Symbol,
        TH.TransactionDate,
        TH.Type,
        1 AS 'EquityType',
        0 AS 'OptionType',
        TH.State,
        TH.Position,
        TE.Shares AS Units,
        TE.SharePrice AS UnitPrice,
        TE.Commission,
        TE.Action,
        '' AS 'Data',
        0 AS StrikePrice,
        '' AS 'ExtendedType'
    FROM TradeHeader TH 
    LEFT JOIN TradeEquity TE ON TE.TradeId = TH.Id    
    WHERE TH.Type = 'Equity' AND TH.State = 'Open'
    );

-- step 2 get options
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PositionDetails AS
    (
    SELECT TH.Id,
        TH.Symbol,
        TH.TransactionDate,
        TH.Type,
        0 AS 'EquityType',
        1 AS 'OptionType',        
        TH.State,
        TH.Position,
        TOP.Contracts AS Units,
        TOP.UnitPrice,
        TOP.Commission,
        TOP.Action,
        TOP.ExpirationDate AS 'Data',
        TOP.StrikePrice AS StrikePrice,
        TOP.OptionType AS 'ExtendedType'
    FROM TradeHeader TH
    LEFT JOIN TradeOption TOP ON TOP.TradeId = TH.Id
    WHERE TH.Type = 'Option' AND TH.State = 'Open'
    );

-- step 3 summarize the data    
SELECT 
    PD.Symbol    
  , MIN(PD.TransactionDate) AS FirstTrans
  , MAX(PD.TransactionDate) AS MostRecentTrans
  , SUM((PD.Units * PD.UnitPrice) + PD.Commission) AS Cost
  , COUNT(PD.Symbol) AS Transactions
  , SUM(PD.EquityType) As EquityTrades
  , Sum(PD.OptionType) AS OptionTrades
FROM PositionDetails PD 
GROUP BY PD.Symbol
ORDER BY PD.Symbol;
```

My question is: how can I get the values for EquityTrades in step 3, without the hardcoded columns I added in my SQL statements step 1 and step 2.

eg, these columns:

```
0 AS 'EquityType',
1 AS 'OptionType',
```

Thnx,
Matt

**EDIT**
Updated SQL below:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PositionDetails AS
    (
    SELECT 
        TH.Id
      , TH.Symbol
      , TH.TransactionDate
      , TH.Type
      , TH.State
      , TH.Position
      , TE.Shares AS Units
      , TE.SharePrice AS UnitPrice
      , TE.Commission
      , TE.Action
      , '' AS 'Data'
      , 0 AS StrikePrice
      , '' AS 'ExtendedType'
    FROM TradeHeader TH 
    LEFT JOIN TradeEquity TE ON TE.TradeId = TH.Id    
    WHERE TH.Type = 'Equity' AND TH.State = 'Open'
    );

INSERT INTO PositionDetails 

    SELECT 
        TH.Id
      , TH.Symbol
      , TH.TransactionDate
      , TH.Type
      , TH.State
      , TH.Position
      , TOP.Contracts AS Units
      , TOP.UnitPrice
      , TOP.Commission
      , TOP.Action
      , TOP.ExpirationDate AS 'Data'
      , TOP.StrikePrice AS StrikePrice
      , TOP.OptionType AS 'ExtendedType'    
    FROM TradeHeader TH
    LEFT JOIN TradeOption TOP ON TOP.TradeId = TH.Id
    WHERE TH.Type = 'Option' AND TH.State = 'Open'
    ;


SELECT 
    PD.Symbol    
  , MIN(PD.TransactionDate) AS FirstTrans
  , MAX(PD.TransactionDate) AS MostRecentTrans
  , SUM((PD.Units * PD.UnitPrice) + PD.Commission) AS Cost
  , COUNT(PD.Symbol) AS Transactions
  , SUM(PD.Type = 'Equity') As EquityTrades
  , Sum(PD.Type <> 'Equity') AS OptionTrades
FROM PositionDetails PD 
GROUP BY PD.Symbol
ORDER BY PD.Symbol;
```

Comment: I believe Step 2 is going to be ignored since step 1 will ensure the table exists. Is there a reason you couldn't just UNION the two SELECTs in a subquery, and then aggregate them in the enclosing query? If you need to be able to differentiate the results in a union based on their origin, you will need something like your "hardcoded columns".

Comment: @Uueerdo step 2 might be a bug.  thanks for catching that.   I thought about a union but haven't been able figure out how I get the functions like SUM(), MIN() to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `EquityType` and `OptionType` columns, just use the `Type` column.

```
SUM(type = 'Equity') AS EquityTrades,
SUM(type = 'Option') AS OptionTrades
```

Your second `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` query should be an `INSERT INTO PositionDetails`, since the table already exists from the first query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE PositionDetails AS
    (
    SELECT TH.Id,
        TH.Symbol,
        TH.TransactionDate,
        TH.Type,
        TH.State,
        TH.Position,
        TE.Shares AS Units,
        TE.SharePrice AS UnitPrice,
        TE.Commission,
        TE.Action,
        '' AS 'Data',
        0 AS StrikePrice,
        '' AS 'ExtendedType'
    FROM TradeHeader TH 
    LEFT JOIN TradeEquity TE ON TE.TradeId = TH.Id    
    WHERE TH.Type = 'Equity' AND TH.State = 'Open'
    );

INSERT INTO PositionDetails
SELECT TH.Id,
    TH.Symbol,
    TH.TransactionDate,
    TH.Type,
    TH.State,
    TH.Position,
    TOP.Contracts AS Units,
    TOP.UnitPrice,
    TOP.Commission,
    TOP.Action,
    TOP.ExpirationDate AS 'Data',
    TOP.StrikePrice AS StrikePrice,
    TOP.OptionType AS 'ExtendedType'
FROM TradeHeader TH
LEFT JOIN TradeOption TOP ON TOP.TradeId = TH.Id
WHERE TH.Type = 'Option' AND TH.State = 'Open';

SELECT 
    PD.Symbol    
  , MIN(PD.TransactionDate) AS FirstTrans
  , MAX(PD.TransactionDate) AS MostRecentTrans
  , SUM((PD.Units * PD.UnitPrice) + PD.Commission) AS Cost
  , COUNT(*) AS Transactions
  , SUM(PD.Type = 'Equity') As EquityTrades
  , Sum(PD.Type = 'Option') AS OptionTrades
FROM PositionDetails PD 
GROUP BY PD.Symbol
ORDER BY PD.Symbol;
```

Comment: With the INSERT INTO do I have to specify columns?  The documentation looks like columns are optional but when do not specify columns I get a SQL error: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.  Perhaps I'm not reading the documentation correctly.

Comment: If you don't specify columns, you have to have values for all the columns, and they must be in the same order as when the table was created.

Comment: that's what is confusing me.  They do have all of the same columns.

Comment: If they did you wouldn't get that error, you must have made a mistake.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't see what I am missing. Can you check my updated SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate a union, this is the basic format:

```
SELECT ..., SUM(subU.someValueField)
FROM (
   ... 
   UNION 
   ...
) AS subU
GROUP BY subU.Xfield, subU.Yfield
```